# How to change gradient settings in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have set up gradient variable scss but the dark color is not so dark (hard to see that it is gradient).

Where can I set contrast of gradient color to make it darker or lighter? Maybe there is variable or something.

> $enable-gradients  true or false (default) Enables predefined gradients via >background-image styles on various components.
>   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/theming/#sass-options

My .scss:

```
$enable-gradients: true;
```

My html:

```
<a href="/login" role="button" class="btn btn-dark mx-2 text-nowrap">Login</a>
```

Comments:

I need .scss solution to change all gradients, not specific buttons or elements.

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: Code of Bootstrap? https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

Comment: No, can you show your code where you implemented it? Your `html` and `css`

Comment: I didn't do anything. Just have basic button. Check answer.

Answer (score 0):

The gradient are built via 2 files :

**First one** : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/utilities/_background.scss

```
@if $enable-gradients {
  @each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
    @include bg-gradient-variant(".bg-gradient-#{$color}", $value);
  }
}
```

**Second One**: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/mixins/_background-variant.scss

```
@mixin bg-gradient-variant($parent, $color) {
  #{$parent} {
    background: $color linear-gradient(180deg, mix($body-bg, $color, 15%), $color) repeat-x !important;
  }
}
```

Just have to overide this job...

Comment: Yeah, I understand this. But can't figure out how it defines saturation of color.

Comment: As you can see it use the mix scss functions... It mix the bg color, with your black colors ... http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#mix-instance_method

Comment: Oh, gonna try. Thanks for reference.